# Can't access 127.0.0.1 apache 2 (MacOS X)

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, localhost

After my MacBook Pro mid2009 has been updated to MacOS X El Capitan I found that many things don't work anymore as they were before.
Built-in apache2 is not aviable on http://127.0.0.1 but aviable on http://localhost. In Yosemite both of them was working properly.

`/private/etc/hosts` looks like that:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1    localhost
```

It's looks strange cuz 127.0.0.1 and localhost are the same thing.
Any idea what's going on?

*httpd.conf*

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Comment: It would appear that `httpd` is binding to `::1` and _not_ `127.0.0.1`. When you use _localhost_, you are connecting via the IPv6 address, please [edit] your question to add in your apache config, and any error log output that may have been generated on statup / binding.

Comment: httpd.conf is added.

Answer (score 1):

In your *httpd.conf*, you will have a `Listen` directive, this will be the ip address / port that the server will bind to.

In your conf file you have defined

```
Listen 80
```

That is stating that you should bind to all interfaces on port 80, this will include both IPv4, and IPv6;

Disabling IPv6 should would, change this line to

```
# allow access on all interfaces
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

# or for local access only
# Listen 127.0.0.1:80

# or more specifically
# Listen 192.168.0.0:80
# To listen on a specific subnet
```

To figure out why the site will not load when accessed via IPv6, would require additional error / debug logs.

Comment: I've tried to change `Listen` a lot of times. No effect. Apache's error log contains just mistakes in .htaccess.